# Comparing distributions - 2-sample and 1-sample tests provide conflicting results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

Firstly, please allow me to preface this by saying that perhaps I do not as yet have sufficient data, hence why I am observing what I am actually observing.  I am looking to address this issue.

Now on to what I am actually observing.

I am trying to determine whether the stock holdings of "skilled" managers contain information about future stock returns.  In particular, we look at the stock holding weights relative to a benchmark stock index.  i.e., we hypothesize that if a stock weighting in a manager's portfolio is greater than the weighting in the benchmark stock index (say, S&P500), then that portfolio holding - in general, but not always - represents a high conviction bet.

Hence, for managers being identified as having some stock selection skill, we wish to test whether these higher conviction bets outperform the lower conviction bets.

Therefore, we test the forward stock returns of the high conviction bets (A) vs the low conviction bets (B).  We expect that mean(A) > 0 and mean(A) > mean(B).

The observation that is confusing me is that:

- The 2-sample test (`ttest_ind()` or `mannwhitneyu()` in python, `scipy.stats`) does not reject the Null hypothesis, i.e., mean(A) = mean(B)
- However, the 1-sample 1-tailed tests (`ttest_1samp()` in python) indicate that mean(A) > 0 and  this is highly significant (p-val <= 0.0001), whilst for mean(B) the Null hypothesis cannot be rejected (i.e., mean(B) = 0)

Therefore, how is it possible that 1-sample tests indicate different means, whereas for the 2-sample test we cannot reject the Null hypothesis?

Comment: Comparing significance between two groups (your second option) is misguided (see e.g. here: https://trialsjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1745-6215-12-264).

Comment: Thank you very much Bjorn.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is in two parts:

**1.**  **Answer to your specific question about apparently conflicting test outcomes**.

A statistical test can be regarded informally as addressing the question: Is the data (statistically) consistent with the null hypothesis? At the abstract level, there is nothing illogical about an outcome that says the data is not consistent with mean A = 0, is consistent with mean B = 0, and is consistent with mean A – mean B = 0. The below example describes the type of data that can bring this about.

Even in ideal application circumstances, your test outcomes are not that unusual. Suppose you have independent samples from two distributions A and B, that have similar positive means but where the volatility of B is much larger than the volatility of A [or, alternatively, A’s sample size is much larger than for B’s]. B sample’s larger variance reduces its t-statistic thus making consistency with the null hypothesis mean (B) = 0 occur much more frequently, and it also makes it harder to achieve a statistically significant result for the difference in means since the variance of the difference in means is the sum of A sample’s variance with B sample’s variance.

**2.    Rolling portfolio methodology**

I think you may be using the wrong methodology, but your description is a bit too concise to be sure. Since different companies’ stock returns are correlated with each other, high conviction returns and low conviction returns will be correlated also, making the standard difference in means test inappropriate. The usual approach in finance would be to construct monthly return portfolios over a number of years, updated on a regular basis, and then do the statistical analysis based on the monthly return differences between the high and low conviction portfolios (see for example the way momentum portfolios are constructed, for which the differences between the winner and loser portfolios are what drives the analyses [Jegadeesh and Titman (2001) Journal of Finance]).

Comment: Thank you very much Graham.

Regarding differences in variance between the two sets, I account for that via a parameter setting whilst calling ttest_ind().  However, the population differences can be rather large.

I think you are spot on re (2) above and was my initial preferred approach, but my manager has a thing about conducting 2-sample tests!  Clearly, due to the high level of correlation, this is not the correct test.